# How do I delay the response for a post

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

How do I delay a response for a post. The following does not work:

```
app.post(/endpoint/, function(req, res){
    setTimeout(()=>res.send(""),1000);
});
```

Comment: Try to add {} to wrap res.send("")
app.post(/endpoint/, function(req, res){
    setTimeout(()=>{res.send("")},1000);
});

Comment: That works fine when I test it. I can't reproduce the problem.

Comment: You could also use: https://www.npmjs.com/package/sleep, but mainly for debugging purposes